# How to fix updating the same info twice in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to make a refactoring of my reducer's, actions' code. The problem is that one state depends on another, so one state is updated and then another one must receive the same info but insted it updates it.
Here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Alopwer/trello-clone).
The folder is src/reducer.

I've tried to separate the states but it gave me more troubles.

F.e. I have two states: boards and currentBoard
What happens in boards:

```
case 'ADD_CARD':
  const { list } = action.payload
    return [
      ...boards.slice(0, list.boardId),
      updateCards(currentBoard, action.payload),
      ...boards.slice(list.boardId + 1)
    ]
```

What happens in currentBoard:

```
case 'ADD_CARD':
  return updateCards(currentBoard, action.payload)
```

How can I rewrite my code to make it better? I expect it at least to be updated once.

Comment: What else have you tried besides separating the states? I suggest implementing a defined order to your dependencies

Comment: I've tried to add in my updateBoards - the currentBoard state as a parameter. But it's not the best solution.

Comment: hey, when we dispatch the action it goes through all the reducers so the suggestion will be just change 'ADD_CARD_CURRENT' some thing like that since no two . reducers should have same actions.

Comment: It's a nice approach but if change the name of the action all the boards will not be updated so i need another solution

Comment: I think I just commented on another question of yours, for this I'd give you the same advice. Look into async actions. You probably want the first `ADD_CARD` to be done modifying the state, and then dispatch another action to do whatever `updateCards` does in the other reducer.

Answer (score 0):

The action 'ADD_CARD' in boards already calls `updateCards(currentBoard, action.payload),` so just remove the `ADD_CARD` from the `currentBoard`.

Also you might want to change the code of `ADD_CARD` action inside `boards` (it's not clean):

```
case 'ADD_CARD':
  const { list } = action.payload;
  const newBoard = updateCards(currentBoard, action.payload);
  list.splice(list.boardId, 0, newBoard);
  return list;
}
```